# How can I avoid escaped delimiter characters in a Unix command?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I need to take the sum of a field which is tilde (~) delimited. Problem I have is that my data is also having delimiter escaped.

#### Example

```
1~CEO~ashok\~kumar~1000
```

As we see in 3rd field above we have escaped delimitter which I want to avoid. I'm running the below command which doesn't handle this.

```
$ cat test.out|awk -F'~' 'BEGIN {sum=0} {sum+=$4} END{print sum}'
```

Assume the `test.out` data as:

```
1~CEO~ashok\~kumar~1000
2~CFO~Ranjan~2000
3~CEO~kumar~1000
```

So my output should be 4000. But currently with my command I get only 3000!

Comment: Since it's the last column, you could simply say: `awk -F'~' 'BEGIN {sum=0} {sum+=$NF} END{print sum}' test.out`

Answer (score 1):

Just change the escaped delimiter to something else before processing with `awk`.  This can be done with `sed`:

```
$ cat test.out| sed 's/\\~/=/g' | \
    awk -F'~' 'BEGIN {sum=0} {sum+=$4} END{print sum}'
4000
```

And, as is often the case, the `cat` is not needed:

```
$ sed 's/\\~/=/g' test.out | awk -F'~' 'BEGIN {sum=0} {sum+=$4} END{print sum}'
```

Comment: That assumes the backslashes themselves are not escaped (things like `field1~field2\\~field\~3` are not found in the input)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative that doesn't use `awk`:

```
$ sed 's/\\~/=/g' test.out | cut -d"~" -f4 | paste -sd+ | bc
4000
```

The above uses `sed` to swap out the escaped tilde `\~` in the 3rd column. Afterwards we can make use of `cut` to select the 4th column of numbers, and then reconstruct them so that they're separated by plus signs, (`+`).

```
$ sed 's/\\~/=/g' test.out | cut -d"~" -f4 | paste -sd+
1000+2000+1000
```

This string is then given to the binary calculator, `bc` which sums them up.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to sum up all value in the last column of each line. so try this:

```
$ awk -F'~' '{sum += $NF};END{print sum}' file
4000
```

If you can use `perl`:

```
$ perl -F'~' -anle '$sum += $F[-1]; END {print $sum}' file
4000
```

or:

```
$ perl -nle '$sum += $1 if /(\d+$)/; END {print $sum}' file
4000
```

Answer (score 1):

To deal with escaping, a general method is to use `perl` or PCRE and their alternation regexp operator combined with the no-backtrack operator. Here with GNU `grep`:

```
grep -Po '(?>(?:\\.|.)*?~){3}\K(?:\\.|[^~])*' << \EOF
1~CEO~ashok\~kumar~1000
2~CFO~Ranjan~2000
3~CEO~kumar~1000
4~field2~field3\\~10000~field5-note-the-escaped-backslash-not-tilde
5~a\~b\~c\~no-4th-field-here
EOF
```

which gives:

```
1000
2000
1000
10000
```

(which you can sum with your usual `awk '{s+=$0};END{print s}'`).

With GNU `sed`, you can also do it with:

```
sed -rn 's/((\\.|[^\~])*~){3}((\\.|[^~])*).*/\3/p'
```

With GNU `awk`, you could use `FPAT` to define fields as sequences of either escaped characters or non-tilde-nor-backslash characters:

```
awk -v FPAT='(\\\\.|[^\\\\~])*' '{print $4}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit clumsy in awk (unless you can preprocess your source to change the delimiter, but that requires knowing another character or character sequence that cannot appear in the input). One thing you can do is read a whole line, then massage the line to get newlines as separators (newlines are the one thing that cannot possibly appear in a line).

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="\n"}
{
    gsub("~", "\n");
    gsub("\\\n", "~");
    gsub("\\\\", "\\");
    $0 = $0;
    print $4;
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for n in $(cat <<\DATA
    1~CEO~ashok\~kumar~1000
    2~CFO~Ranjan~2000
    3~CEO~kumar~1000
DATA
)
    do r=$((r+${n##*~})) ; done
echo $r

###OUTPUT
4000
```

Given the data you show a simple `for` loop can do it, but if there's a chance of `<tab>` or `<space>` in the data you might want to limit the splitting like:

```
IFS='
'
```

...first.

Or with `sed` and `bc`:

```
sed 's/.*[^0-9]/r+=/;$aprint r' <<\DATA | bc
    1~CEO~ashok\~kumar~1000
    2~CFO~Ranjan~2000
    3~CEO~kumar~1000
DATA
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
4000
```

Both methods rely on your target data being the last field in each line.

The first does simple shell iterable `$((`arithmetic`))` on `$((r))` after stripping everything up to and including your last delimiter from `$n`.

The second replaces all that removed in the first method with the string `'r+='` and `|pipes` the result to `bc` which then does `r=r+${last_field}`. On the `$`last line of input `sed` also `a`ppends another line:

```
print r
```

...and `|pipes` it to `bc` which then does as instructed and outputs as shown.