# parse colon separated value pairs, with escaped colon characters in field(s)

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, jq

I'm trying to process output from nmcli command (colon separated values), but failing to handle / ignore escaped colons in MAC or BSSID. I've tried awk, jq, sed, regex but just not getting it...

piped command:

```
nmcli -f SSID,BSSID,CHAN,FREQ,SIGNAL,SECURITY -t dev wifi
```

example output:

```
WiFi:00\:0A\:97\:6F\:7B\:AC:165:5660 MHz:15:
```

If I move BSSID to the end of the line / field's list (and then just cut the last field) it'll work, but now it's a matter a pride. Please help!

I did find this existing stackoverflow thread, which really went about it nicely, but I'm ultimatly running into the same problem of how to ignore the escaped colon in the MAC!@%$ address:
[parse colon separated value pairs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399222/parse-colon-separated-value-pairs/399757)

Most recent (readable) attempt:

```
printf '%s' "$(nmcli -f SSID,BSSID,CHAN,FREQ,SIGNAL,SECURITY -t dev wifi)" | jq -sR 'split("\n") | map(split(":")) | map({"SSID": .[0], "BSSID": .[1], "CHAN": .[2], "RATE": .[3], "FREQ": .[4], "SIGNAL": .[5], "SECURITY": .[6]})'
```

and problem output:

```
...
{
"SSID": "WiFi",
"BSSID": "00\\",
"CHAN": "0A\\",
"RATE": "97\\",
"FREQ": "6F\\",
"SIGNAL": "7B\\",
"SECURITY": "AC"
},
...
```

Would also need JQ to leave colons in place and not escape as shown above, if at all possible, ... please don't just say python...

Comment: what's the desired end-state? 6 variables? a CSV file?

Comment: `read` will do it, as will `cut`. split on colons, then ask for fields `1, 2-7, 8,9,10, and 11`.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) for SE to distribute that content. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, consider taking a look at: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 3):

A few notes here:

- You can prevent `nmcli` from escaping the fields with `--escape/-e no`
- You don't have to quote json field names (without special characters)
- `SSID` and `Security` don't always get returned so I added a placeholder (`--`)

  ```
  printf '%s' "$(nmcli -f SSID,BSSID,CHAN,FREQ,SIGNAL,SECURITY -e no -t dev wifi)" |
    jq -sR 'split("\n") |
      map(split(":") |
      {SSID: (if .[0] == "" then "--" else .[0] end), 
        BSSID: .[1:6] | join(":"),
        CHAN: .[7],
        FREQ: .[8],
        SIGNAL: .[9],
        SECURITY: (if .[10]  == "" then "--" else .[10] end)})'
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Perl allows you to construct a field separator with lookbehind - and also handily provides a [JSON module](http://search.cpan.org/~ishigaki/JSON-2.97001/lib/JSON.pm). So you could do something like

```
nmcli -f SSID,BSSID,CHAN,FREQ,SIGNAL,SECURITY -t dev wifi | 
  perl -F'(?<!\\):' -MJSON=encode_json -lne 'print encode_json([map { s/\\:/:/g ; $_ } @F])'
```

Testing with your example `nmcli` output:

```
printf 'WiFi:00\:0A\:97\:6F\:7B\:AC:165:5660 MHz:15:' | 
  perl -F'(?<!\\):' -MJSON=encode_json -lne 'print encode_json([map { s/\\:/:/g ; $_ } @F])'
["WiFi","00:0A:97:6F:7B:AC","165","5660 MHz","15"]
```

Comment: @LordVance FWIW on Ubuntu, I simply had to install the `libjson-perl` package

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed` to clean the data, and [`mlr`](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) to turn it into JSON:

```
h='SSID,BSSID,CHAN,FREQ,SIGNAL,SECURITY'
nmcli -f $h -t dev wifi | 
sed 's/^:/"",/;s/\([^\]\):/\1,/g;s/[\]:/:/g' | 
mlr --c2j --jvstack  --jlistwrap  label $h
```

Output example:

```
{
  "SSID": "FooBarBaz",
  "BSSID": "13:F6:8C:56:9B:3B",
  "CHAN": 36,
  "FREQ": "5180 MHz",
  "SIGNAL": 20,
  "SECURITY": "WPA1 WPA2"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

GNU awk can handle fields as sequences of either escaped characters or non-colon-nor-backslash characters (see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129373/271639)), so the following should work. Not very efficient, but at least a solution...

```
#!/bin/bash
line="WiFi:00\:0A\:97\:6F\:7B\:AC:165:5660 MHz:15:"
# line=`nmcli -f SSID,BSSID,CHAN,FREQ,SIGNAL,SECURITY -t dev wifi`
for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do
    echo $line | gawk -v FPAT='(\\\\.|[^\\\\:])*' '{print $'$i'}' 
done
```